# Run YAML task2 only if task1 is not skipped

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YAML pipeline with an existing structure that cannot be changed. I'm trying to add some additional logic to it and am stuck with the existing condition logic.

I have two tasks:

```yaml
- task: task1
- task: task2
```

`Task2` should run if `Task1` succeeds or fails, but should NOT run if it is skipped.

Here is what I've tried that does not work:

- `SucceededOrFailed()` does not work since it is looking at the status of the pipeline as a whole, not a specific task
- `dependsOn` does not work as it only applies to jobs. These tasks cannot be refactored into their own jobs because of the existing structure of my YAML
- Using `task.setvariable` in a shell task between tasks 1 and 2  to define a variable that can be used in the task2 condition does not work because my pipeline is agentless and cannot run PS/shell tasks.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```yaml
# while this does work in a script, it doesn't seem to work in a condition statement
condition: ne(variables['task.task1.status'], 'Skipped')
```

or

```yaml
# doesn't exist
condition: eq(Skipped('task1'), 'false')
```

Comment: Hi @Alana, Based on the requirements, it is required to run the tasks in **single** job, so, multiple dependency job status check is not applicable; it is required to run the tasks in an agentless job, the evaluation of output variable by build timeline API request is not applicable. Bright's answer is as expected, as specifying `condition` property for `Task2` with the same condition of `Task1` overwrites its default evaluation of Succeeded `Task1`. Therefore, if `Task1` is skipped, `Task2` will skip as well; if `Task1` is not skipped, `Task2` will continue without checking `Task1` status.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to get the status of task in pipeline.

Normally, a task gets skipped in pipeline run, it should be because the **`condition`** set on this task is evaluated as '**`False`**'.

For your case, you want that **`task2`** can be skipped if **`task1`** gets skipped. You just need to set the **`condition`** of **`task2`** to be same as that of **`task1`**.

- If the **`condition`** is evaluated as '**`True`**', **`task1`** will run. Then regardless of whether **`task1`** is success or failed, **`task2`** also will run.
- If the **`condition`** is evaluated as '**`False`**', both **`task1`** and **`task2`** will be skipped.

Comment: Totally agree. This is working based on the requirement, since according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cjobs). *When you specify your own `condition` property for a stage / job / step, you **overwrite** its default `condition: succeeded().`*

Comment: This is so smart, and would probably work for 99% of cases, but in my case, `Task1` is not being skipped because of a condition, but for *other reasons* that I'm still learning about. When you look at the pipeline timeline, other skipped tasks have `"startTime": null`, but my `task1` has a valid start and end time. I believe that the owner of the task is doing some magic to sense that the task shouldn't be run, and then marking it as skipped.

Comment: @Alana, Can you provide a demo of pipeline that can reproduce the same situation like as you descript? We may need to check if there is any configuration in the pipeline definition could cause this.

Comment: @Alana, In addition, maybe, you also can try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to ask the engineer team to add pipeline variable that can get the task status.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the conditions for task execution are evaluated before any tasks are run;

what you can do is use a combination of job outputs and a script to archive the desired behavior :

```
  steps:
    - task: task1
      name: task1
      displayName: 'Run Task 1'
      # Your task1 configuration

    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task1Status]$(task1.status)"
      name: setTask1Status
      displayName: 'Set Task 1 Status'

    - task: task2
      displayName: 'Run Task 2'
      # Your task2 configuration
      condition: eq(dependencies.MyJob.outputs['task1.setTask1Status.task1Status'], 'Succeeded') 
    enter code here
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that conditions for tasks are evaluated before tasks are run. That helps me understand why what I'm trying to do seems so hard. Unfortunately, like I mentioned in my original question, my tasks are running agentless/serverless, so I cannot run a script task : `'Job1' is a server job, but contains task 'CmdLine' which can only run on agents.`

Comment: Can you give me more details about the service or platform you're using I might help more if I have extra informations

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only [few tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks) are supported in agentless job.

If you check `classic UI editor` for agentless job task, you can see there is no `Run this task` condition setting as Agent job task.

[image]

But only on `agentless job level`.

[image]

Hence, as an alternative, you can put the task into two agentless job.

Yaml sample which is working on my side:

```
jobs:
- job: agentlessjob1
  pool:
    name: server
  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    displayName: 'Manual Validation'
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: 'xxxx@hotmail.com'
      instructions: test


- job: agentlessjob2
  dependsOn: agentlessjob1
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  pool:
    name: server
  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    displayName: 'Manual Validation'
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: 'xxx@hotmail.com'
      instructions: test
```

[image]